# How to determine distance to a point on arc perpendicular from tangent?

Tags: geometry

Given the following from the image below:

- The green circle has a radius equal to **B**
- The yellow line is tangent to the green circle
- The vertical purple line is parallel to the green line and perpendicular to the yellow line.
- The yellow line is perpendicular to both the green line and the vertical purple line
- The purple point is centered on the green circle's edge
- **A** and **B** are known values

I realize several of these constraints overlap, just trying to be thorough.
Pythagorean's theorem can provide the value of **C**, just to illustrate what I know we can determine already.

What is the formula/equation to determine **D**, where **D** is the perpendicular distance from the tangent yellow line to the arc/circle (at the purple point)?

[image: Perpendicular Distance To Point From Tangent]

**Update**

Replacing previous attempts to illustrate solution now with one that I can now visualize as the correct representation of the answer and comments provided by John

[image: Solution Imagery]

Comment: right thought - wrong place.  Treat C as a red herring (useless information). Consider a radius going from center to purple P).  Extend a line (A') LEFT from the purple (length = A), intersecting radius B at B' then you should have a better triangle to give Pythagorus with legs of B' and A':)  If you need a bigger hint (or a drawing), let me know, I'll post it as an answer

Comment: Yes, I agree C may be useless, I only put it in there to illustrate what else we could determine and is not meant to necessarily be part of the solution for D.

Comment: one more hint, that should avoid the need to give you the answer.  If you followed my comment above - D = B - B'

Comment: See my update with the image, is this, combined with the more detailed answer below what you are suggesting here?

Comment: Bingo! You get a cookie :) (don't ask, I'm in a cookie mood, at the moment)

Comment: About to start testing but before I do, am I missing a line in the proposed drawing to make it clear? It seems to me I am missing a representation and/or C' is in the wrong place for it to be part of the triangle for A' and B'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139410/discussion-between-streamline-and-john).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance D can be found by computing the lowest intersection between the vertical ray from the right endpoint of the yellow segment and the circle.

Some notations (`x` axis to the right, `y` axis to the bottom, origin at the center of the circle):

- center of the circle: `P_C = (0, 0)`
- origin of the vertical ray: `P_O = (A, B)`
- direction of the vertical ray: `v_d = (0, -1)`

Points on the ray satisfy: `P = P_O + t v_d = (A, B - t)`

Points on the circle satisfy: `|P P_O|^2 = B^2`

Expanding the first equation into the second gives: `A^2 + (B - t)^2 = B^2 = A^2 + B^2 - 2 B t + t^2`

Solving `t^2 - 2 B t + A^2 = 0` for `t` yields `d = B^2 - A^2 > 0`, so two solutions `t_1 = B - sqrt(d)`, `t_2 = B + sqrt(d)` (one near the bottom of the circle, the other near the top as expected). But `t` actually gives the distance along the ray (since `v_d` is a unit vector), so what we are looking for is the smallest solution `t_1`. Hence `D = B - sqrt(B^2 - A^2)`.

The final result can also be derived and / or verified geometrically (courtesy of John, see all the corresponding comments): `D = B - B'` and `B'^2 + A^2 = B^2` (Pythagorus on the right triangle with the center of the circle and the purple point as two of its vertices and an edge sitting on the purple line).

Comment: without all the technical, it seems you got close to where I was, but I can't follow the "half" - as mentioned above, D=B-B', B' (by pythagorus) = sqrt( b^2 - a^2), therefore D = B-sqrt(b^2-a^2), where'd the half come in?  -- Nevermind, while adding the comment, you lost the half

Comment: Yes, that was a mix-up between standard and simplified discriminant.

Comment: See my update with the proposed drawing attempting to clarify how we get to the solution. Does that illustrate your answer?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and alignment with the comments provided by John. I updated the post with an illustration I believe represents both in a way I can visually digest.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned C is the easy part. However with A,B,C and the cosine theorem you can work out the angel opposite to B (b):

```
cos(b) = (a^2 + c^2 -b^2)/(2ac)
```

knowing b and that A and D have a right angel you can work out the angle between C and D (b'):

```
b' = 90° - b
```

given that D lies on the circle you know that the distance from the center to D is B so you now have a triangle with sides B,D and C where you know two of the sides and one of the angles. With the cosine law again:

```
B^2 = C^2 + D^2 - 2CD cos(b')
```

so in one more step we can find:

```
B^2 - C^2 = D^2 - 2CD cos(b') + (C cos(b'))^2 -(C cos(b'))^2 <=>
B^2 - C^2 + (C cos(b'))^2 = (D - C cos(b'))^2 <=>
sqrt(B^2 - C^2 + (C cos(b'))^2) + C cos(b') = D
```

hope I didn't put stupid mistakes in there and this helps...